# Pre-downloading on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

State Of Decay 2 releases in under a week now, and I was hoping to pre order the game digitally. If I do pre order through my Xbox One, digitally, will I have access to download the game prior to its release, so I can head straight into it instead of a large download. Is it possible?

Comment: Since the game hasn't been released yet, this question could be closed as off-topic. To avoid this, you might want to ask if the Xbox One supports pre-loading games or not. Chances are it depends on the game, though.

Comment: @Nolonar specifically does this game allow it?

Comment: The problem is that we won't know until pre-loading starts, which could happen a few hours to a week before official release. And once the game is released, this question would be useless to any future visitors.

Comment: Is getting a physical disc version a better alternative?

Comment: Not necessarily. There's always a possibility for a day 1 patch, so when you put the disk in, you still need to wait for the update to install. With a digital copy, the game is already patched the moment you download it. For most games, those patches are only a fraction of the entire game's data, but I've seen examples where the patch is almost as large as the game itself.

Comment: If you look around news sites for something along the lines of the title "Gone Gold", that means it is completed and on its way to be preloaded shortly after. Not every game posts this news, but it does give hints at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/State-Of-Decay-2-Ultimate-Edition-Preorder/9N1X7CD94CHM):

> Description:
>
> State of Decay 2: Ultimate Edition includes:
>
> • Early Access - play State of Decay 2 four days early before the
>   game’s standard release date • State of Decay: Year One Survival
>   Edition (Console version) • Independence Pack* • Daybreak Pack*

On the Special Edition, you will get it four days early.

The other editions of the game will come out on the original release date.

Now [this](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2014/08/12/gamescom-xbox-one-gamescom-press-release/) is based on a press release in 2014, BUTTTTTTTTT it does say you can pre-load pre-ordered games.  You just won't be able to use them until release dates.

> In response to customer feedback, Xbox also announced the ability to
>   pre-order and pre-download games on Xbox One. Fans will be able to
>   pre-order and pre-download “Forza Horizon 2” prior to its official
>   release on Sept. 30 – this will also be available for “FIFA 15,” with
>   more titles to come. Pre-order and pre-download gives gamers
>   additional options for where they can purchase game content and the
>   ability to purchase in their preferred format. This also enables the
>   title to download ahead of availability, so gamers can begin playing
>   immediately upon the release of the game.

Now keep in mind, all of this is based on the publisher.  If the publisher WANTS to allow pre-loads, they can.  This is just a feature Microsoft has allowed for less restrictions toward the publishers and their content.

Comment: Pre-loading games is set up and functional yes, but it is still up to the dev/publisher to upload the release when it is ready to pre-load, some games still come down to the wire and are released digitally at midnight or release day, while others come up weeks in advance.

Comment: Not going to disagree.  I'll edit it.  I was just putting it up there as "it's an xbox option/feature"